# How to cancelLocalNotification When app is in the background And I don't do anything

Tags: ios, background, clock, localnotification

Thank You in advance
Xcode 7.3 ,oc 
Now I'm using the LocalNotification to make an alarm clock .I ran into a problem and consulted a lot of people who didn't get the answer .When I receive a LocalNotification, app is in the background, And I don't do anything ,Means I will not click on the LocalNotification or start app. how do I listen to the system received LocalNotification ?I would like to receive the LocalNotification for the next step.Or, how do I listen to the system started playing audio .In addition, how can I guarantee that even if the app is suspended in the background, I can listen to it. I can't think of a way out of it.

Can you help me ?

Thank You 
Thank You 
Thanks very much

Comment: Welcome to SO, check out how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You should add some code, explain what you have tried and where you have failed!

Comment: I think you are asking "how can you run some code when the local notification is delivered, if the user doesn't tap it?"  the answer is "you can't"

Comment: how can a local notification come when the app is in backend.. this question looks inconsistent

Comment: "how can you run some code when the local notification is delivered, if the user doesn't tap it?" .This is what I mean .Really, I can not do it?